# memory grows when switching to a new scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the game in which the new scene is called by pressing buttons. When you click in a new scene sent the corresponding pictures. When you return back to the game map memory always increases by 30 MB. I do not understand where the strongest link. Instruments can not detect leaks. Sorry my english. Help me please.

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        for i in 0...3 {


            if  childNode(withName: "button\(i)")!.isHidden == false && childNode(withName: "button\(i)")!.contains(location)  {
                buttonOfBattlefield = childNode(withName: "button\(i)")
                }
            }


                switch buttonOfBattlefield?.name {
                case "button0"?:
                    battlefieldName = "A"
                case "button1"?:
                    battlefieldName = "B"
                case "button2"?:
                    battlefieldName = "C"
                case "button3"?:
                    battlefieldName = "D"

                default:
                    break
                }

            if battlefieldName != nil {
                let myScene = GameScene(size: self.size , battlefield: battlefieldName!)
                myScene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
                let reveal = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 2.0)
                self.view?.presentScene(myScene, transition: reveal)


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you segue back from this secondary view? Are you properly deinitializing it?

Comment: I used deinit for the test. It works

Comment: Are all the images in the second scene being deinitialized?

Comment: In the second scene so many images. Needless to them personally deinitialized?

Comment: If the button is pressed again then the memory is not growing. It remains grown as the first press

Answer (score 1):

Essentially there could be many factors that cause the increase of memory in your game.

I try to help you with some useful correction.

Speaking about custom protocols, you could break the strong references by adding `class` at the end of the line, and declare `weak var` to the delegate:

```
protocol ResumeBtnSelectorDelegate: class {
    func didPressResumeBtn(resumeBtn:SKSpriteNode)
}

weak var resumeBtnDelegate:ResumeBtnSelectorDelegate?
...
```

Speaking about `completion` could be a strong reference to `self` so you can do like this example:

```
self.launchVideo(completion: {
   [weak self] success in
   guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
   //self.showMyVideo()
   strongSelf.showMyVideo()
}
```

same thing to run actions blocks:

```
let exp = SKAction.run {
          [weak self] in
          guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
          strongSelf.getExplosion(percentageDimension: 15,type: 0,position: enemy.position)
}
```

If you use third part library in objective C , you may need to remove the strong references also there:

```
__weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction followPath:_ascentPath duration:1.5], [SKAction runBlock:^(void){[weakSelf explode];}]]];
[self runAction:sequence];
}
```

If you have some observer try to remove it, samething for NSTimers to the `willMoveFromView` methods.

```
override func willMove(from view: SKView) {
   //remove UIKit objects, observers, timers..
}
```

Comment: Alessandro Ornano Thanks you! But I'm blonde and newbie

Comment: My brain began to boil. If we use only one texture, such as "A", the memory does not increase. How to weaken the link to the texture?

Comment: some memory increases are lawful, are due to the spritekit caching system, as with sktexture.The important is that at the change of skscene, memory is decreased in the new scene.

Comment: The application falls on the iPhone 4s (> 250 MB) if I increase the number of textures. On iPhone 5 - no.

Comment: A good thing you could do when you make a game is to take care of assets: use JPG, few PNGs only when you needed, your images must not be too large.How do you measure this? Check the App Store file sizes on  itunes connect to understand how many mbytes you could use for you project.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your clues led me to a clever thoughts!

Comment: I'm happy to know this answer help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution found. The new Game Scene need to use the method.

```
self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*"){ (node, stop) -> Void in
        node.removeAllActions()
        node.removeAllChildren()
        node.removeFromParent()
    }
```

Thank you all for your help. I'm happy!